# Fetching Char(1) column with Informatica Export mode returning error

Tags: teradata, informatica, informatica-powercenter, fastexport

I am using TPT FastExport in Informatica source. In the source Teradata table, there is a column with datatype char(1). When I run the workflow, I am getting an error as Source column data length is 3 but the Target column data length is 6.

I am not facing issues with Varchar or numeric columns.

Comment: Are you using UTF8 session character set? Try UTF16 instead.

Comment: Can you share the error details? It does seem like UTF issue.

Comment: Hi Fred.. Any reason for going to UTF16 as all the required characters are available in UTF8

Comment: Hi Maciejg, I am getting an error as 
"TPTRD_306 : [ERROR] Type:(Teradata PT API Error), Error: (TPTAPI_INFRA: API306: Error: Conflicting data length for column" while running PowerCenter session with TPT Export Operator and UTF-8 code page"